# Randomly rounding 0.5 up or down with a seed in R

Tags: r, rounding, seeding

I have a data set containing non-integer values that I want to *round to the closest integer*. This is pretty easy, but I need a function that does two things in addition to just rounding:

1. It should rounds the halves (0.5,1.5,2.5 etc.) either up or down randomly while still always flooring e.g. 2.4 and ceiling e.g. 2.6
2. I want the function to give the exact same results each time while still rounding around half of the middle cases up and half of them down.

Comment: Have you posted question and answer at the same time?

Comment: Yes, I did post an answer but wanted to share it with others and improve my solution. See https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Since, according to the OP, not only the numbers that are strictly equal to the .5 rounding limit but also those which are very close to it should be considered as candidates for random up- or down-rounding, the exact condition `x%%1==0.5` can (or should) be dropped. In that case it is sufficient to add a very small perturbation to all numbers before rounding. The `jitter()` function adds such a random perturbation, which affects the results of the rounding. This is done in a reproducible way depending on the seed value. The tolerance range that determines which numbers are "random rounding candidates" would be the size of the jitter, which can be specified with the optional parameter `amount`.

One could therefore use a function like this:

```
random_round <- function(x, seed = 123, tol = 1.e-6) { 
                  set.seed(seed) 
                  round(jitter(x, amount = tol))
                 }
```

Comment: Wouldn't this include a (very small) chance of falsely rounding a value differing from .5 by adding the jitter?

Comment: Well, suppose within a vector to be rounded there's the value `2.49999999999`, adding a jitter of `0.0000000001` would change the rounding from 2 to 3. It is extremely unlikely though.

Comment: I'd say refrain from deleting for now. Maybe someone else has an idea how to improve your solution. As I see it, all solutions proposed until now (mine as well, as you thoughtfully pointed out) have their issues and are not bulletproof.

Comment: Nice, that should prevent any unwanted changes in rounding behaviour! +1

Comment: I think replacing `x%%1 == 0.5` with `near(x%%1,0.5)` would solve the issue, right? (At least in my case) values close to 2.5 can be treated as being equal to 2.5.

Comment: @SamuelSaari Thank you for this clarification. I am not aware of the function `near()` but I have edited my answer in order to account for your comment. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could further vectorize your solution by using `ifelse`, making the `sapply` unnecessary:

```
FOO <- function(x, seed){
  set.seed(seed)
  ifelse(x %% 1 == .5, round(x + sample(c(-1, 1), 1) * .01), round(x))
}

test <- c(4.5, 3.4, 6.8, 3.5)

FOO(test, 1)
[1] 4 3 7 3
```

This is multiple times faster. Microbenchmark:

```
set.seed(10)
test <- sample(1:10, 10000, replace = T)
test <- test - sample(seq(0, 1, .1), 10000, replace = T)

microbenchmark(LAP = FOO(test, 1),
               Samuel = round_r(test), unit = "ms", times = 1000L)

Unit: milliseconds
   expr       min        lq      mean   median        uq      max neval cld
    LAP  1.172478  1.197225  1.493402  1.20718  1.237616 158.8736  1000  a 
 Samuel 41.040701 46.280868 50.014392 49.02561 52.908411 215.4537  1000   b
```

---

Another, about 30% faster edition suggested by @AndreElrico:

```
FOO2 <- function(x, seed){
  set.seed(seed)
  ifelse(x %% 1 == .5, sample(c(ceiling,floor),1)[[1]](x), round(x))
}
```

Comment: can you test if this is faster: `ifelse(x %% 1 == .5, sample(c(ceiling,floor),1)[[1]](x), round(x))`

Comment: @AndreElrico It is indeed about 30% faster!

Comment: Just add it in your post if you like :-)

Comment: Done :) Nice suggestion!

Comment: @RHertel Yeah, I wondered about the viability of the equality operator in regards to floating points. This might cause issues.

Comment: @RHertel Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think in this specific case the comparison should be OK, as `0.5` is an exact binary fraction, `0.1` (i.e. `2^-1`)?

Comment: @MikkoMarttila Indeed, I think you are right. I had not noticed that this is a special case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should `sapply()` over every single number when you can just vectorize it.

```
round_rs <- function(x) {
  set.seed(111)
  x + sample(c(0.5, -0.5), length(x), replace = TRUE)
}

table(round_rs(v[v %% 1 == 0.5]))
```

Or, complete:

```
 round_rs <- function(x) {
  set.seed(111)
  rn <- v %% 1 == 0.5
  x[rn] <- x[rn] + sample(c(0.5, -0.5), sum(rn), replace = TRUE)
  x[!rn] <- round(x[!rn])
  x
}

microbenchmark(LAP1 = FOO(test, 1),
               erocoar = round_rs(test), 
               LAP2 = FOO2(test), unit = "ms", times = 1000L)

Unit: milliseconds
    expr      min       lq      mean   median       uq       max neval
    LAP1 1.388751 1.402546 1.8448210 1.488841 1.631277 77.461753  1000
 erocoar 0.464842 0.472542 0.7619839 0.483449 0.535098 75.046116  1000
    LAP2 0.994486 1.009243 1.2846360 1.061694 1.165955  3.814334  1000
```

Comment: Upvoted, as yours is truly vectorized. Still, @RHertel's objection regarding the viability of the equality operator with floating points is relevant for both our answers.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Based on [RHertel's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4770166/rhertel) answer, I have edited the code to suit this specific case even better.

In phase I, a function is created that jitters and rounds values very close to n + 0.5 . In phase II the function is applied to all  non-integer values at given variables.

**SETUP**

```
library(tidyverse)
var1 <- c(rep(10.5,10^4),rep(20.1,10^4),rep(30.9,10^4))
var2 <- c(rep(10.5,10^4),rep(20.1,10^4),rep(30.9,10^4))
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(var1,var2))
```

**PHASE I**

```
round_r <- function(x,seed=111, tol=1.e-6) { 
  set.seed(seed) 
  round(ifelse(near(x%%1,0.5), jitter(x, amount = tol), x))
}
```

**PHASE II**

```
data2 <- data %>% mutate_at(vars(var1,var2),
                      funs(ifelse(.==.%/%1,.,round_r(.))))

# results
table(data)
table(data2)

> table(data)
var2
var1  10.5  20.1  30.9
10.5 10000     0     0
20.1     0 10000     0
30.9     0     0 10000

> table(data2)
var2
var1  10    11    20    31
10  4994     0     0     0
11     0  5006     0     0
20     0     0 10000     0
31     0     0     0 10000
```

Remember to erase the row with set.seed if you want truly random roundings!

If the code can still be improved, I would like to hear!